# Vim - open tab with specific file

Tags: file, vim, tabs, find

if I have multiple tabs open, for example 10, those have multiple splits,
and one of the splits has a file open that is called for example "TestFile".
Is it possible to jump to the tab that has that file open?

Something like `tabfind TestFile`?

Plugins would be nice too.
I use CommandT, put it does not have that feature as far as I know.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `:sb <buffer>` as long as you have set the following: `:set swb=usetab`. Without this the current window will just be split to show the file instead of the tab.

For your example this would be: `:sb TestFile`.